# Is there an existing gem or script that converts numbers to comp-3/packed decimal format?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cobol, comp-3

Continuing with my adventure to convert COBOL to a Ruby program, I have to convert a decimal digit to a comp-3/packed decimal format. Anyone know of a simple Ruby script or gem that does this?
Berns

Comment: This should take you about 5 minutes to write...

Comment: Hi Mark-Andre. Do you know where I might find the algorithm, or at least an explanation of the algorithm that would help me understand how to spend those five minutes? I understand nipples (or nybbles) are involved, and a byte can have exactly 2, which means all of my digits should end up looking great! :)

Comment: I looked at http://www.3480-3590-data-conversion.com/article-packed-fields.html and answered with some code. Good luck.

Comment: Actually, there's even builtin nibble packing in Ruby. Who knew. Answer updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ruby knows how to pack nibbles, so it turns out to be quite easy:

```
def pack_comp(n)
  s = n.abs.to_s + (n < 0 ? "d" : "c")
  s = "0" + s if s.size.odd?
  [s].pack("H*")
end
```

Comment: No problem. And no, you're not. BTW, it did take me more than 5 minutes :-) And my first solution was overkill too.

Comment: Idiots are only geniuses who don't realise it yet.

Comment: to_s produces "nibbles" (4 bit values)?  I'm not a Ruby expert, but they look like just string characters (8 or 16 bit values) to me.

Comment: @Ira: Indeed, `to_s` does not produce nibbles, it just converts to a string (i.e. does the decimal expansion). It is `pack("H*")` that "converts" these characters to nibbles. HTH